Как отключить плеер-меню toolkit:MediaElement?
Как регулировать видимость этого меню? (communityToolkit:MediaElement)
Хочу поставить видео на весь экран как фон. Но это проклятое меню мешает всей красоте. Можно ли его как-то отключить?

Если отключить/регулировать его никак нельзя, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, инструменты в xaml, чтобы можно было поставить фоновое видео точно также, как и изображение. Спасибо.

У MediaElement есть свойство ShouldShowPlaybackControls, поставьте его на false
